# Every application(mobile applications) is connected to its server.Is there any way to identify that server address?

Tags: android, url, mobile, server, ip

Every app has its own server.Can we find that server address or the url that is requesting by that specific app?I am specifically saying about android phone.

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can! By using burpsuite you can analyze the request sent by that app and type of request and domain name too.

Burpsuite: Burpsuite is Tool used by cyber security researchers to find vulnerabilites and analyze the data sent and recieved.
[For details of burpsuite visit here!](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/what-is-burp-suite/)

Comment: I didnt get you .can you please tell me exactly what is burpsuite

Comment: Sir I meant if there is any code like sample codes for finding it.Because I am trying to develop an app.